# Invalid-key request passed to a map to retrieve the value. Handle this exception

Tags: javascript, dictionary, hashmap, key-value

I have a map, and am trying to retrieve a **value** based on the **key** passed in the form of "id". However in some cases, the "id" that is passed is invalid i.e. it is not present in the Map, which in turn makes the application crash. Is throwing the Error causing this issue ? I tried experimenting with the try-catch but it still continued to malfunction i.e. the screen stops loading on detecting this error. Not sure if I wrote the try-catch correctly. how do I best handle this to stop the application from malfunctioning in such a case and continue loading the screen.

Failed approach:

```
    this.hmItems = {};   //Map<Integer,Item>
    Address.prototype.getItem = function (id) {
            var item = this.hmItems[id];
            if (!item)
                throw new Error("'Illegal argument: id=" + id);
            return item;
    };
```

Another failed approach:

```
this.hmItems = {};   //Map<Integer,Item>
Address.prototype.getItem = function (id) {
   try {
       var item = this.hmItems[id];
       if (!item) throw "illegal id!!!!!!!!!";
       return item;
       } catch(err) {
       //log exception
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `hasOwnProperty` to see if the property exists on the `hmItems` object:

```
this.hmItems = {}; //Map<Integer,Item>
Address.prototype.getItem = function(id) {
  if (!this.hmItems.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
    throw new Error("'Illegal argument: id=" + id);
  }
  return this.hmItems[id];
};
```

Just checking `var item = this.hmItems[id]; if (!item)` isn't a good test because it'll fail even if the property exists on the object but is falsey, like 0 or null.

Live demo:

```js
class Address {
  hmItems = {
    1: 10,
    2: 0
  };
  getItem(id) {
    if (!this.hmItems.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      throw new Error("'Illegal argument: id=" + id);
    }
    return this.hmItems[id];
  }
}

const a = new Address();

// Works:
console.log(a.getItem(1));
// Works:
console.log(a.getItem(2));
// Throws:
try {
  console.log(a.getItem(3));
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
```